# Style sheets not working if port specified - node.js express

Tags: css, node.js, express, stylesheet

For some reason if i specify port to listen in server.js, for example `4242`, but not  `process.env.PORT`, my .css files stop working (with `process.env.PORT` it's working).

Code example:
Server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express()
  , http = require('http')
  , server = http.createServer(app)

app.get('/room', function (req, res) {
    res.render('room.ejs')   
});

server.listen(4242);
```

room.ejs:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
///rest of HTML///
```

`style.css` file itself is in `public` folder that is in site's folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try telling express wheres the static folder located in the `server.js`:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

and change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />  //see the / on css route
```